# Esri Geometric Network - Error Code 18 (unknown)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, personal-geodatabase, geometric-network

We have created a geometric network in a Personal Geodatabase with ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Each time we are getting an error code of 18 on a particular point feature.

As you can see [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002r00000006000000), there is no error code of 18 according to the Esri table.

We have submitted this to Esri but have not gotten a response.

Rather than just deleting the point and recreating it, we want to know exactly why this happened.

Has anyone ever seen a geometric network error 18 or know what this means?

Comment: What kind of geodatabase are you seeing this error from?

Comment: Personal (requirement).

Comment: check to see the error exists with FileGeodatabase. Make sure your geometries are simple and single part. And report back here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got an answer from ESRI about this issue. The full error code list is mentioned [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s00000062000000).

> Error code 18: The feature has an invalid subtype value.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the full list of error codes. This brought up another issue that was fixed as well. Long story short - the subtype was manually input via text in the field calculator, rather than the coded domain value or choosing the subtype from the dropdown menu. And all is well in the world again. Thanks again.